# Flutter: Can you tell how many Google Maps API Calls are being made

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps

In flutter, am using the 'google_maps_flutter' plugin to display a google map, and trying to understand how best to implement a fee structure (through In App Purchases).

In my case, I foresee the app being used infrequently but when used, it would be a high usage of the google maps API.

So I feel a subscription plan wouldn't be appealing, and the best fee structure would be for users to buy consumable credits.

For this to work, I need to be able to know how many API calls a user makes, so I can deduct them from the credit.

But I can't seem to find any documentation to determine how many API calls are being made.

Comment: I had the same issue. I was using the geocoding API, direction API, nearby places, and places API. and it was too costly. I get rid of all the APIs except the direction API. I removed the places API and alternatively, I am using the geocoding and reverse geocoding package, which is free but has limitations. I am using the direction API for polyline points and after that, I send the user to google maps. And for nearby places, I also send the user to google maps. Now the cost is normal and in control. So if you want to apply subscription, it will still be costly for you.

Comment: Have you tried checking your Billing reports or metrics page on the console?